# @Stateless or @Singleton instead of static helper class?

Tags: multithreading, unit-testing, jakarta-ee, ejb

I'm maintaining some older JEE code which runs fine but is using some static helper classes where an entity manager is passed in the methods from the calling EJB(s) like this:

```
public class StaticHelper {

    public static void helpingOut(EntityManager entityManager, String value) {
        // i.e. insert value
    }
}
```

Since this doesn't seem to fit JEE very well and is not nice to unit-test, I've converted these helpers to `@Stateless` EJBs like so:

```
@Stateless
public class StatelessHelper {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="SuperUnit")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void helpingOut(String value) {
        // i.e. insert value
    }
}
```

Like that I can inject a mocked helper in the calling EJB with [CDI-Unit](http://bryncooke.github.io/cdi-unit/).

Now, depending on the load, 1-3 instances of that stateless helper is created by the container which isn't a problem at all I would say, but anyway I thought about a `@Singleton` using either `@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN)` or `@Lock(LockType.READ)` to make it multithreaded - but this doesn't seem to be a good idea since `EntityManager` is not thread-safe. Or does this [explained here](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/is_in_an_ejb_injected) still apply?

> "...The container serializes calls to each stateful and stateless
>   session bean instance. Most containers will support many instances of
>   a session bean executing concurrently; however, each instance sees
>   only a serialized sequence of method calls. Therefore, a stateful or
>   stateless session bean does not have to be coded as reentrant..."

Comment: You're not creating the `EntityManager` instance yourself. The container does that. So the citation doesn't apply on it at all.

Comment: Your @Stateless bean is simple and inherently thread safe. You have nothing to gain by looking at more complex solutions

Comment: just out of curiosity: what do you mean by "this [...] is not nice to unit-test"? pure static functions (not depending on any external state, only their args) are IMHO testability nirvana, no?

Answer (score 1):

Business methods in Java EE (or the more recent denomination Jakarta EE) should be implemented in `@Stateless` beans. That is what they are ment for. So the approach you just describe perfectly fits into the Java EE paradigm.

`@Singleton`s are ment for instances containing application-wide state.

`@Singleton` for beans containing business methods are models from other techologies, like Spring or Guice. In those, the business methods are not synchronized, so you have to beware that every class level attribute must be thread safe. This is not Java EE model, in which one thread is assured to access one instance of a Session Bean at any specific time (by specification), and that's what makes it safe to use with `EntityManager`.

This doesn't happen with `@Singletons`, and so, to use them concurrently you have to tune them with `@ConcurrencyManagement`  annotations.

What you just did is just right.

**Clarification**

It looks like I said Singleton Session Beans are not thread safe. What I ment is that concurrent access to the single instance is not allowed by default (the other way round as in Spring or Guice), and so they can be bottlenecks for business methods. To allow concurrent access you have to tune them with the aformentioned `@ConcurrencyManagement`.

Answer (score 0):

I created a [simple project](https://github.com/ermalaliraj/ejbconcurrency) for checking/testing how the container handles transactions in `SLSB` and `Singleton`. Cases I covered are:

- Using `@PersistenceContext EntityManager` inside `SLSB`
- Using directly a `@Datasource` inside `SLSB`
- Using a `@Datasource` inside a `@Singleton`

Below the conclusions of the test.

### EntityManager ([DashboardEM](https://github.com/ermalaliraj/ejbconcurrency/blob/master/ejbconcurrency-server/src/main/java/com/ea/ejbconcurrency/ejbimpl/DashboardEM.java))

- `EntityManager` is reliable. With the default isolation level it is enough to avoid data inconsistent.
- When a *concurrent exception* happens the container will rollback, so handle appropriately **system exceptions** in order to not lose data. In our case a `OptimisticLockException` is thrown so we resend the *point* to the *dashboard*.
- A "*copy*" of `EnityManager` is injected to each `SLSB` instances by the container. Afterwards it is the `EntityManager` responsible for data consistency.
- `SLSB` is *safe* in sense that container guarantees only one thread at time can execute a **single instance** (but different instances runs concurrently in separate threads)

### @Singleton  ([DSSegmentSingleton](https://github.com/ermalaliraj/ejbconcurrency/blob/master/ejbconcurrency-server/src/main/java/com/ea/ejbconcurrency/singleton/DSSegmentSingleton.java))

- Makes sense to use `@Singleton` only if you are using directly a *source*. With `Lock.WRITE` you increase the isolation levels between threads/instances to `SERIALIZABLE`.
- It creates a bottleneck, all the threads (clients) have to wait after each other in order to execute the method.
- Lose the benefit of having multiple stateless instances in the pool (implies that multiple clients can do stuff at the same time).
- In case of `@Singleton` the execution time would increase with the increase of clients because each would wait on each other. For 100clients, the 100th client would wait 99 x *single execution time*.
- In case of `@Singleton` the execution time increases as the number of concurrent clients goes up. For example: if 100 clients call the `Singleton SLSB` at the same time, the last client would have an execution time of ( 99 x *execution time* ).

### Other Solutions when you don't have EntityManager

- Use isolation level directly in DB  (`select ... for update`). See [DashboardDSSelectForUpdate](https://github.com/ermalaliraj/ejbconcurrency/blob/master/ejbconcurrency-server/src/main/java/com/ea/ejbconcurrency/ejbimpl/DashboardDSSelectForUpdate.java)
- Using `TransactionManagement(BEAN)` and changing isolation level of the connection like `conn.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE);` See: [DashboardDSTxBean](https://github.com/ermalaliraj/ejbconcurrency/blob/master/ejbconcurrency-server/src/main/java/com/ea/ejbconcurrency/ejbimpl/DashboardDSTxBean.java)

## See also

- [project here](https://github.com/ermalaliraj/ejbconcurrency): The source code
- [JSR-318 EJB 3.1 Spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3.1-pfd-oth-JSpec/) - Enterprise JavaBean 3.1 Specification
- [Concurrency in a Singleton](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/ejb-basicexamples002.htm#JEETT00657!) - 34.2.1.2 Managing Concurrent Access in a Singleton SB
- [Isolation Levels](http://javadata.blogspot.be/2011/05/dirty-readphantom-read-and-non.html) - Real example of *Dirty Read*, *Phantom Read* and *Non Repeatable Read*
- [Reentrant Lock](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/locks.html) - Simple explanation of reentrant locks in Java.
- [OptimisticLockException](https://www.mkyong.com/jpa/jpa-optimistic-lock-exception-in-java-development/) - Example when OptimisticLockException is thrown.